# Getting the type of a value in APL

Tags: types, apl, dyalog

I have a long vector which should be a character vector but when I print it using Dyalog's DISPLAY function it turns out to be a mixed vector. Now I need to find out which of the elements is not a character. How do I retrieve the type of a value in APL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `⎕DR` ([**D**ata **R**epresentation](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/Data%20Representation%20Monadic.htm)) to check the type of things. For a char-vec, it's 82 (on a 32-bit interpreter) or 80 (64-bit) - and since the 64bit-platform supports unicode, it could be 160 or 320 as well. A nested vector is 326.

**NB:** you can also use `⎕DR¨` to investigate which element is not as you expected...

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Strangely enough, for the vector *v* in question, ⎕DR¨ *v* returns a vector where all elements are 82, despite *v* being a mixed vector rather than a character vector.

Comment: It may well be that one of the elements of your vector is a vector (of length 1) itself. Use `⍴¨` to get some insight on that...

Comment: I tried `{⍬ ≡ ⍴⍵}¨ v`, but it evaluates to a vector where all elements are 1. If I'm not mistaken, this implies that no element is a vector.

Comment: Where did that vector come from? If it was created by a fn, it might help to see the code..

Comment: Sorry, on the first try I didn't spot the offending element. The expression `({82 ≠ ⎕DR ⍵}¨ v) / ⍳⍴v` gave me the position (282), which holds a one-element vector with the integer zero.

Comment: Ok, thanks for finding that!  I was really confused when you said it was all scalars ;-)

Comment: Correction: `(({82 ≠ ⎕DR ⍵}¨ v) / ⍳⍴v) ⊃ v` is zero.

Comment: BTW, if you're using V17, you can do `⍸bool` instead of `bool/⍳⍴bool`  ;-)

Comment: @MBaas And so can you if you're using version 16.0.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on APL2.
Naïvely I'd go for

```
X≡¨⍕¨X
```

Numeric values get a 1 and character values get a 0.

[Like this](https://tryapl.org/?a=X%25u2261%A8%25u2355%A8X%25u2190%27A%27%20%27ABC%27%20%27123%27%20123%20%281%201%25u2374%27F%27%29%20%282%204%25u2374%25u23738%29&run)

Answer (score 0):

The expression* `⊃0⍴⊂A` gives you the type of `A`. The type of an array is, simply put, a copy of the array but all content recursively replaced with zeros for numbers and spaces for characters. This means that you can compare the type with `0` to find numbers.

Take for example the following vector with a somewhat deceptive default display form:<sup>[Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%u22A2v%u2190%27abc%27%2C1%202%2C%27de%203%204%27%2C5&run)</sup>

```
      ⊢v←'abc',1 2,'de 3 4',5
abc 1 2 de 3 4 5
```

The boxed display form doesn't tell you the type of each element of a simple vector; it only indicates that the array has mixed type with a `+` in the bottom left corner:<sup>[Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%5Ddisplay%20v%u2190%27abc%27%2C1%202%2C%27de%203%204%27%2C5&run)</sup>

```
      ]display v
┌→───────────────┐
│abc 1 2 de 3 4 5│
└+───────────────┘
```

Now we find the type:<sup>[Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=v%u2190%27abc%27%2C1%202%2C%27de%203%204%27%2C5%20%u22C4%20%u22A2t%u2190%u22830%u2374%u2282v&run)</sup>

```
      ⊢t←⊃0⍴⊂v
    0 0        0
```

We can stack it on top of the original vector to point at the numbers:<sup>[Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=v%u2190%27abc%27%2C1%202%2C%27de%203%204%27%2C5%20%u22C4%20t%u2190%u22830%u2374%u2282v%20%u22C4%20%u2191t%20v&run)</sup>

```
      ↑t v
    0 0        0
abc 1 2 de 3 4 5
```

Or we can compare it to zero to get a mask for the numbers:<sup>[Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=v%u2190%27abc%27%2C1%202%2C%27de%203%204%27%2C5%20%u22C4%20t%u2190%u22830%u2374%u2282v%20%u22C4%20%u22A2m%u21900%3Dt&run)</sup>

```
      ⊢m←0=t
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Finally, we can get the indices where** there are numbers:<sup>[Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=v%u2190%27abc%27%2C1%202%2C%27de%203%204%27%2C5%20%u22C4%20t%u2190%u22830%u2374%u2282v%20%u22C4%20m%u21900%3Dt%20%u22C4%20%u2378m&run)</sup>

```
      ⍸m
4 5 12
```

---

<sup>* If you are using `⎕ML←0`, then `⊃0⍴⊂` can be written as the single primitive function `∊`

** If you are using version 15.0 or earlier you will have to write `{(,⍵)/,⍳⍴⍵}` instead of `⍸`</sup>